# Mixing both Azure and AWS in one setup

Tags: asp.net, azure, amazon-web-services, azure-sql-database

> Disclaimer: I'm not sure this question is a good fit for StackOverflow, but I
>   haven't found any "cloud-computing" stackexchange, and the official
>   "meta" post instructs me to ask this on StackOverflow.

Has anyone tried, or explored options to have part of your infrastructure running on AWS and another part - on Azure, and if yes - is there any technology that can connect the two clouds bypassing "public internet"? Something similar to AWS Direct Connect, but for AWS-Azure link.

Specifically, I'm thinking of running an **app-server on AWS** (Windows EC2-instance running ASP.NET) and a **database server on Azure SQL Database**.

If anyone tried doing that in the same/close region (for example, both providers have datacenters in Virginia) - how did you do it and did you have any network latency/bandwidth issues.

Comment: Questions asking for pros and cons are too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @mason ok, will edit it to be more specific

Comment: Your question is still too broad. Sorry, it's just not a good fit for Stack Overflow. We're for solving specific programming problems, dealing with code. Not explaining how to set things up or potential things to watch for.

Comment: Using app-server on AWS and Database server in Azure is a wrong choice. The latency will impact your overall application performance.

Comment: @Ashan - when modeling for DR, multi-cloud is not a wrong choice, even when egress charges and latency come into play. But... again, that's why this question is off-topic - it's very broad and opinion-soliciting.

Comment: If you plan for DR and HA, you can address the two in different manner. For DR, its a choice having another environment in a same cloud provider different regions, different cloud provider or on premise. When it comes to database its mostly asynchronously replicated environment or ETL jobs to DR site. 

When it comes to HA, mostly its achieved in the same could provider. In AWS Having Multiple AZs and in Azure, running multiple environments behind load balancing.

Comment: Having web server in one and accessing DB server in another cloud environment for DR is still a wrong choice. It should be a decision towards replicating the Web Server and DB Server environment synchronizing DB with the required strategy.

Answer (score 3):

This is what's called [Polynimbus](https://buildazure.com/2016/12/23/the-polynimbus-cloud-enterprise/). A Polynimbus organization is one that utilized multiple cloud providers, and is EXTREMELY common.

Generally, you're not going to mix AWS and Azure services within the same application or system if you can help it. Just as communicating across Azure Regions incurs Egress charges and adds network latency on the wire, so does communicating across from/to Azure and AWS.

There are MANY organizations that are using both AWS and Azure. Some applications might be architected and "stuck" in a certain cloud provider for various reasons. These apps will likely stay there for the long term, but then new (ala green field) application may be put into one cloud or the other based on features, pricing, or other business requirements / requests.

You can also achieve higher levels of Availability and Resiliency by utilizing multiple cloud providers. For example, you might host multiple web application instances across multiple Azure Regions, and then implement Load Balancing across them for high availability. Then, you could also setup 1 or more instances of the same web application in AWS in a Failover load balancing configuration. This would protect you from both Azure Regions going down, by automatically failing over to AWS. You could also implement it the other way around, or just choose to use AWS as an offsite backup from Azure. It really depends on how worried / paranoid you are about a given cloud providers data centers going down for some reason.